# Python - basic arithmetic/variable names

Tags: python

The assignment is to write a program that spits out an odd number, a number, and then does basic arithmetic on those numbers. I've gotten it to spit out outputs fine, but I cannot seem to find a way to have the generated numbers be part of the equation. Here is the code I have:

```
odd = int(input("Please enter an odd number from 1 to 99: "))
print(int(odd))
num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 200: "))
print(int(num))
print('odd + num =',odd+num)
print('odd - num =',odd-num)
print('odd * num=',odd*num)
print('odd / num =',odd/num)
print('odd + num =',num+odd)
print('odd - num =',num-odd)
print('odd * num =',num*odd)
print('odd / num =',num/odd)
```

I need the 'odd / num =' section to be replaced with the numbers generated, but I'm unsure as to how to do that and my textbook says nothing about it.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `print( odd, "-", num,"=",odd-num)` or `print(f"{odd}-{num}={odd-num}")` or `print('{}-{}={}'.format(odd,num,odd-num))` or the outdated % formatting one... based back in pre-python-3

Comment: You are even printing `odd` and `num`, so you had the solution before your eyes... `print(odd, '+', num, '=', odd+num)` or `print("%d + %d = %d" % (odd, num, odd+num,))` or `print("{} + {} = {}".format(odd, num, odd+num)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do something like this:

```
print('{} + {} = {}'.format(odd, num, odd+num))
print('{} / {} = {}'.format(odd, num, odd/num))
```

and so on for the other operations.